Visual Studio - Proxy Authentication Required - Connecting to packages.nuget.org
Since last week, I’ve been having trouble opening previous projects in Visual Studio. A small window keeps popping up asking for 'Proxy Authentication Required' (see image below). I’ve tried nearly everything, including reinstalling Visual Studio, but nothing seems to work.
Any idea how to solve this?






There's a proxy that sits between you and nuget.org/the web that requires authentication. Are you on a company network by any chance?

yes, I didn't had a problem at all so far.

Sounds like something changed. You may need to raise a ticket with your company's network support.

Are you able to install nuget packages if you add V3 Feed and uncheck V1 Feed in your package source?
The V3 feed URL is https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
The V1 feed URL is https://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc
Then please check if the NuGet.config file is configured for any proxy settings.
For example:
  <v1>
     <add key="Username" value="xxx" />
     <add key="Password" value="xxx" />
  </v1>

Docs Referred:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#packagesourcecredentials
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/consuming-packages-authenticated-feeds#credential-providers

I uncheck V1 and let only V3 now is working. Thank you!
